# UTM32 vs. WGS84

Tags: wgs84, utm

I am conducting an GIS analysis for areas for Germany.

While the OSM map, which I really like to use (copyright issuses etc.) is in WGS-84, all the data from offical map services in Germany come in UTM 32N.

I have no trouble converting them to WGS-84 but I wonder how accurate WGS-84 may be...

QGIS states for UTM32 "best possible accuracy 0,1m" while for WGS-84 "best possible accuracy 2,0m".

I have no idea how big  (if there are any) the deviations might be if I use WGS-84. Or am I thinking completely wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation where it states that?  It's either wrong or being misinterpreted.

Comment: Accuracy is not really a property of an individual CRS. No CRS is more "accurate" than any other. What I think you are seeing here is the accuracy of transformation, reported by QGIS, and that involves *two* CRSs, for example if you load UTM32 data into a project using WGS84. Is that it? Can you show us the dialog where these accuracy reports are coming from?

Comment: @Spacedman I think you are right. I probably misinterpret the dialog. QGIS shows this when I try to convert (save as/export) a shape and change the CRS orginally UTM to WGS-84....the dialog is in german but it will show when i hover of the caution sign